# Mounting (potentially faulty) harddisks

Tags: filesystems, mount, hard-disk

I have had a Lacie 2Big Triple RAID harddrive ages ago, and there are some family photos I didn't copy before the case broke. I tried to put the old hard disks into a reader, but the disk cannot be mounted.

For the first disk:

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model:  Disk           
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1           1 976773167 976773167 465.8G ee GPT
```

I only redacted the internal disk from the fdisk output.

```
# file -sk /dev/sda
/dev/sda: DOS/MBR boot sector; partition 1 : ID=0xee, start-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), end-CHS (0x3ff,254,63), startsector 1, 1953366015 sectors, extended partition table (last)\012-  DOS/MBR boot sector\012-  GPT partition table, version 1.0, GUID: 8868abf6-211c-4f2d-9f22-44778cbe6b2b, disk size: 1953366016 sectors\012-  of 512 bytes\012- data
```

And gdisk for disk 1:

```
# gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Warning! Disk size is smaller than the main header indicates! Loading
secondary header from the last sector of the disk! You should use 'v' to
verify disk integrity, and perhaps options on the experts' menu to repair
the disk.
Caution: invalid backup GPT header, but valid main header; regenerating
backup header from main header.

Warning! One or more CRCs don't match. You should repair the disk!
Main header: OK
Backup header: ERROR
Main partition table: OK
Backup partition table: ERROR

Partition table scan:
  MBR: protective
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: damaged

****************************************************************************
Caution: Found protective or hybrid MBR and corrupt GPT. Using GPT, but disk
verification and recovery are STRONGLY recommended.
****************************************************************************
Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Model:  Disk           
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 8868ABF6-211C-4F2D-9F22-44778CBE6B2B
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 1953365982
Partitions will be aligned on 8-sector boundaries
Total free space is 262157 sectors (128.0 MiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
   1              40          409639   200.0 MiB   EF00  EFI System Partition
   2          409640      1953103831   931.1 GiB   AF00  Mike
```

The second disk:

```
# fisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 465.76 GiB, 500107862016 bytes, 976773168 sectors
Disk model:  Disk           
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

And file:

```
# file -sk /dev/sda
/dev/sda: data
```

gdisk for disk 2:

```
# gdisk -l /dev/sda
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 1.0.8

Partition table scan:
  MBR: not present
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present

Creating new GPT entries in memory.
Disk /dev/sda: 976773168 sectors, 465.8 GiB
Model:  Disk           
Sector size (logical/physical): 512/512 bytes
Disk identifier (GUID): 963D4F54-1270-451A-A1A0-0BEA70978DF7
Partition table holds up to 128 entries
Main partition table begins at sector 2 and ends at sector 33
First usable sector is 34, last usable sector is 976773134
Partitions will be aligned on 2048-sector boundaries
Total free space is 976773101 sectors (465.8 GiB)

Number  Start (sector)    End (sector)  Size       Code  Name
```

To my knowledge, RAID1 was used (mirror). I didn't find any IDs for these disks.

I tried DiskWarrior and mounting it on a Mac too, but thought Linux would be my best option. However, I am a bit out of ideas. If you see disks like those above, are there any tips on how I could mount these disks again and access the files?

I am willing to buy or install any other tools but I need recommendations.

Comment: Do you know which RAID mode was used by the case? According to [this user manual](https://www.lacie.com/files/lacie-content/manual/2bigtriple_en.pdf) the default mode would have been "FAST" (RAID 0), but the contents of the MBR partition table of your disk 2 suggest that the "SAFE 100" (RAID 1) mode may have been used. But the case actually used GPT partitioning, the contents of the protective MBR may have been inaccurate.

Comment: What is the output of `file -sk /dev/sda` for each disk?

Comment: If you expect the drives to be faulty, or for data recovery in general, you should `ddrescue` a full copy of these disks before doing anything else. And then proceed with better tools - your flavor of fdisk is unable to handle gpt partitions.

Comment: Thank you @frostschutz if you have recommendations for tools, please let me know

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I updated my questions, thanks! This command seems very useful

Comment: @telcoM I think it was RAID1, that one that mirrors files. The file command output I added might also indicate in that direction

Comment: (1) The output of `file` for "disk 1" matches the output of `fdisk` for "disk 2" and vice versa. Please review. In case I'm right, [edit] the question and fix the mix-up. Label the disk cases with sharpie or assign their serial numbers to "disk 1"/"disk 2", so they won't get mixed up again. (2) What is the output of `gdisk -l /dev/sda` for each disk?

Comment: `ddrescue` is a good idea if the disks may be faulty. Then probably `dmsetup` will help. See [this](https://superuser.com/q/1130337/432690) and [this](https://superuser.com/q/1115400/432690); and I'm sure there are other solved questions like those. My point is we've done this before, you're in the right place, the chances are you will get the family photos out.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski thank you very much for your advises. I have updated my post with the correct output order and also the gdisk. I used a perm marker to not mix up again. I check your links and ddrescue now

Answer (score 2):

Partition size roughly twice the drive size, so most likely raid0, chunk size to be determined, though the device also supports concatenation... Partition alignment is weird, 40 sector offset... oh well, it's old.

Lame way to determine chunk size by trial&error (using a Linux live environment like system-rescue or similar). For a better method, you'd have to look at the raw data (find a JPEG header offset, and puzzle it together. If it's off by 20K that's because of the partition alignment).

Create read-only loop devices:

```
# losetup --find --show --read-only /dev/sda
/dev/loop0
# losetup --find --show --read-only /dev/sdb
/dev/loop1
```

Build read-only mdadm raid0 (without metadata):

```
# mdadm --build /dev/md42 \
        --level=0 --chunk=64K \
        --raid-devices=2 /dev/loop0 /dev/loop1
```

Note: for some reason, `mdadm --build` does not allow `mdadm --readonly` option to be used, so read-only-ness of this step depends on read-only of the loop device. It's better to make such attempts on a copy, or copy-on-write overlay…

Check if it's anything:

```
# file -s /dev/md42*
/dev/md42:   DOS/MBR boot sector …
/dev/md42p1: DOS/MBR boot sector, code offset 0x3c+2, OEM-ID "mkfs.fat" …
/dev/md42p2: SGI XFS filesystem data …
```

The partitions should always show up (switch drive order if it doesn't), but that doesn't mean it's mountable.

Mount read-only (using another layer of read-only loop device, since some filesystems still try to write in ro mode):

```
# mount -o loop,ro /dev/md42p1 /mnt
# ls /mnt
…any files?
# umount /mnt

# mount -o loop,ro /dev/md42p2 /mnt
# ls /mnt
…any files?
# umount /mnt
```

If it does mount, and if it does list files, you should still find a file several chunks large and verify its contents. It's possible for things to mount and still be corrupt, so you need an intact large file to make sure.

If it fails in any step, start over and try a different chunk size.

```
# mdadm --stop /dev/md42
# mdadm --build … --chunk=128K
```

Rinse and repeat for 64K 128K 32K 256K 16K 512K 4K ... and hopefully it will work with one of them.

If none work, you can also try with `--level=linear` (no chunksizes).

Comment: This looks great! Do I need to physically attach both disks at the same time? I can only connect one disk at a time, I would need to buy another piece of hardware. Maybe I can do this on some kind of an image as well? Is this something I can do with ddrescue?

Comment: Yes, of course... I did recommend to use ddrescue anyway. losetup will also work on an image file. You just need a place to store them.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks for the confirmation. I am now creating the images, which most likely will take me 10 hours or so. Will report back then if your solution worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I have tried this, but it looks different.
File: /dev/md42: data

I don't have md42p1 or 2.
And mdadm brings this.
NTFS signature is missing.
Failed to mount '/dev/loop2': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop2' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Comment: Does fdisk -l, gdisk, ... show partitions for the image / loop-device like it did in your question? Then the copy should be good and it should show partitions for /dev/md too (switch drive order of mdadm command if it doesn't). Which Linux environment are you using? If fdisk doesn't show GPT partitions chances are it's something old, try current SystemRescue or similar. In the end its very difficult to say what's going on remotely - my answer is at best a guess how it could work according to your post so far. You might have to figure it out on your own, sorry.

Comment: Or wait... I just saw to flip devices, which did the trick. I can now see three partitions, two with MBR, one (unfortunately) HFS extended with only 58 GB size. I have installed hfsprogs and run this: fsck.hfsplus -f /dev/md42p2
It brought up: Invalid number of allocation blocks

I know this is hard to do remotely, but if this final output tells you something, I am glad about pointers. It seems this disk is messed up, as far as I can tell now

Comment: /dev/md42p2 should be 931.1 GiB according to your earlier output. What does it look like in lsblk? Even if the partition shows up, the chunksize may be wrong, so do try different chunksizes. fsck would not work if you made it read-only, and as long as the filesystem is not corrupt, you should not need fsck in the first place.